# Binding a NSArrayController to a NSPopupButton & NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

What I want to accomplish seems like it should be fairly straightforward. I have placed a sample project [here](https://github.com/ericgorr/arraycontrollerbindings).

I have a NSArrayController filled with an array of NSDictionaries.

```
[[self controller] addObject:@{ @"name" : @"itemA", @"part" : @"partA" }];
[[self controller] addObject:@{ @"name" : @"itemB", @"part" : @"partB" }];
[[self controller] addObject:@{ @"name" : @"itemC", @"part" : @"partC" }];
```

I am populating a NSPopupButton with the items in this array based on the 'name' key. This is easily accomplished with the following bindings

[image: bindings]

I would then like to populate a NSTextField with the text in the 'part' key based on the current selection of the NSPopupButton. I have setup the following binding:

[image: textfieldbindings]

With these bindings alone, the text field does display 'partC'.

[image: initial display]

However, if I change the value of the NSPopupMenu, what the text field shows does not change.

I thought this would simply be a matter of setting up the 'Selected Object' binding on the NSPopupButton

[image: selected object]

but that isn't working. I end up with the proxy object in my menu for some strange reason (providing the reason why would be a bonus).

[image: window2]

So, what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: What about setting model key path for your popup button?

Comment: For which binding? To what? Setting the model key path of 'selected object' to 'part' just results in 'partC' showing up in the menu and an exception being thrown when I change the menu option.

Comment: Follow what I wrote in Cocoa Dev mailing list.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Don't use "Selected Object" in this case.  Bind the pop-up's "Selected Index" binding to the NSArrayController's `selectionIndex` Controller Key. Tried it out on your sample project and it works.

EDIT:

You asked why it's appropriate to use `selectionIndex` over `selectedObject`. First some background:

When binding a popup menu, there are three virtual "Collections" you can bind: **Content** is the abstract "list of things that should be in the menu" -- you must always specify **Content**. If you specify neither **Content Objects**, nor **Content Values**, then the collection of values bound to **Content** will be used as the "objects" and the strings returned by their `-description` methods will be used as the "values".  In other words, the **Content Values** are the strings displayed in the pop-up and the **Content Objects** are the things they correspond to (which are possibly not strings, and which might not have a `-description` method suitable for generating the text in the pop-up). What's important to realize here is that there are potentially three different 'virtual arrays' in play here: The array for **Content**, the array for **Content Objects** (which may be different) and the array for **Content Values** (which may also be different). They will all have the same number of values, and typically, the **Content Objects** and **Content Values** will be functions (in the mathematical sense) of the corresponding items in the **Content** array.

The next thing that's important to realize is that part of `NSArrayController`'s purpose in life is to keep track of the user's selection. This is only mildly (if at all) interesting in the case of a pop-up, but starts to become far more interesting in the case of an `NSTableView`. Internally, `NSArrayController` keeps track of this by keeping an `NSIndexSet` containing the indexes in the **Content** array that are selected at any given time. From there, selection state is exposed in several different ways for your convenience:

- `selectionIndexes` is as described - an `NSIndexSet` containing the indexes of the selected items in the **Content** array
- `selectionIndex` is a convenient option for applications that do not support multiple selection. It can be thought of as being equivalent to `arrayController.selectionIndexes.firstIndex`.
- `selectedObject` is also useful in single selection cases, and corresponds conceptually to `ContentObjectsArray[arrayController.selectionIndexes.firstIndex]`
- `selection` returns a special object (opaque to the consumer) that brokers reads and writes back to the underlying object (or objects in the case of multiple selection) in the **Content Array** of the array controller.  It exists to enable editing multiple objects at a time in multiple selection cases, and to provide support for other special cases. (You should think of this property as read-only; Since its type is opaque to the consumer, you could never make a suitable new value to write into it. It's meaningful to make calls like: `-[arrayController.selection setValue: myObject forKey: @"modelKey"]`, but it's *not* meaningful to make calls like `-[arrayController setValue: myObject forKey: @"selection"]`

With that understanding of the `selection` property, let's take a step back and see why it's not the right thing to use in this case.  `NSPopUpButton` tries to be smart: You've provided it with a list of things that should be in the menu via the **Content** and **Content Values** bindings.  Then you've additionally told it that you want to bind its **Selected Object** to the the `NSArrayController`'s `selection` property. You're probably thinking of this as a "write only" binding -- i.e. "Dear pop-up, please take the user's selection and push it into the arrayController", but the binding is really bi-directional.  So when the bindings refresh, the popup first populates the menu with all the items from the **Content/Content Values** bindings, and then it says, "Oh, you say the value at `arrayController.selection` is my **Selected Object**. That's odd -- it's not in the list of things bound with my **Content/Content Values** bindings. I'd better add it to the list for you! I'll do that by calling `-description` on it, and plunking that string into the menu for you." But the object you get from that **Selected Object** binding is the opaque selection object described above (and you can see from the outcome that it is of class `_NSControllerObjectProxy`, a private-to-AppKit class as hinted by the leading underscore).

In sum, *that's* why binding your popup's **Selected Object** binding to the array controller's `selection` controller key is the wrong thing to do here. Sad to say, but as I'm sure you've discovered, the documentation for Cocoa bindings only begins to scratch the surface, so don't feel bad. I've been working with Cocoa bindings pretty much daily, in a large-scale project, for several years now, and I still feel like there are a lot of use cases I don't yet fully understand.

Comment: This is what I wrote to the same post on Cocoa Dev list.

Comment: If anyone would like to provide a more detailed explanation as to why, I would be interested.

Comment: @ericgorr Tried to explain some more; hope it makes sense. It's a complex topic.